# Unexpected "Use of unassigned local variable" error when assigning variable inside a boolean conjunction

Tags: c#

Let's suppose we have these two dictionaries:

```
var dict1 = new Dictionary<string, int>();
var dict2 = new Dictionary<char, string>();
dict1.Add("foo", 42);
dict2.Add('x', "bar");

// These variables will be used for getting values from the dicts
int number;
string text;
```

We can use `text` without problems inside an `if` assigning it a value (in this case, via `out`) in the `if`'s condition:

```
// Example 1
if(dict1.TryGetValue("foo", out number) &&
    dict2.TryGetValue('x', out text))
{
    Console.WriteLine(text); /* Prints: bar */
}
```

**But**, if we take the condition out to a boolean variable, it **won't compile**:

```
// Example 2
var canPrint =
    dict1.TryGetValue("foo", out number) &&
    dict2.TryGetValue('x', out text);
if(canPrint)
{
    Console.WriteLine(text); /*Use of unassigned local variable 'text'*/
}
```

To make things weirder, if we change the order of `canPrint`'s terms, it **does** compile:

```
// Example 3
var canPrint =
    dict2.TryGetValue('x', out text) &&
    dict1.TryGetValue("foo", out number);
if(canPrint)
{
    Console.WriteLine(text); /* Prints: bar */
}
```

I think this is because the way in which the compiler determines the assignation of variables (specifically, when they are defined in a boolean expression).

Anyway, it surprised me that the first and second example, being apparently so similar, have such different results.

Why does this happen?

Comment: I don't know C# very well - but does it matter that you are mixing single and double quotes? "foo", 'x'

Comment: @peeldog in C# "double quotes" are for strings, single quotes are for chars.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because of the so-called short-circuiting. In the following condition if `dict1.TryGetValue("foo", out number)` is false, the `dict2.TryGetValue('x', out text)` won't be evaluated so `text` won't have a value.

> if (dict1.TryGetValue("foo", out number) &&
>                   dict2.TryGetValue('x', out text))

if the condition is `true`, it means that both of the predicates are evaluated, which means `text` is initialized, and if it is `false`, the block which tries to access the `text` won't be executed.

But why `if(canPrint)` doesn't work. Actually the point is that you can assign `true` to `canPrint` independently while it has been `false` and `text` has not been initialized. So, there is no guarantee and the compiler complains.

And finally, to see the effect of the short-circuiting, swap the place of two conditions, then both of them (due to the way you are using them) will work.

Comment: Yes, this is basically correct. Because of the short-circuit in the evaluation using the `&&` the second condition may never get evaluated, so the variable could never be set. It is valid in the case where you are using it in the `if` statement, however when you set the boolean value separately the compiler doesn't know that it could not reach that.

Comment: I'm aware of the short circuit. Anyway, if that were always true, the example 1 (short circuit inside an `if`'s condition) shouldn't work.

Comment: To emphasize gmiley's point I would bet the fact that it is first is why the last example compiles.  You would be guaranteed evaluation of the var text.  The fact that it produices true I would think is not what the compiler looks at.

Comment: @Sam When it is inside of the `if` evaluation, the compiler sees that and can infer that the condition is what determines it printing. When it is not associated with the `if` evaluation, the compiler does not see the relation and only sees the boolean check, therefore it is invalid.

Comment: This is a seemingly odd case, but when you look closely, it is really the only way it could/should be handled by the compiler.

Comment: Why/how does the compiler knows how to deduce the consequences of the short circuit if the condition is declared inside the if? I.e. How does it know "if we short circuit before `text` is assigned, we will never enter this block, so it's safe". Essentially, what's the semantic difference for the compiler between examples 1 & 2? It seems like a by design behavior. I would appreciate any links on how the compiler does this analysis

Comment: Yep, as @mok specified, the fact that the evaluation is done within the `if` evaluation means that it is "safe", while if the boolean is set outside and then checked, it could have been changed at any time between.

Comment: theoretically the compiler can infer this. Just a guess from here - it is probably not an interesting enough case that warranted developing this, because imagine the code is a little bit more involved and the evaluation happens down the line in the code. a lot more context would be required, and the lines one when it should and shouldn't work become more blurry.